# How to allow the user to change the language?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I think I must be missing something here.

I have enabled the multilingual modules and added a language. It all seems to be working with respect to translating content - an admin can easily translate an individual page. However I can't see how to give an anonymous user the ability to change their selected language. I was expecting the multilingual modules to create Blocks that would allow a user to change their default language and which would notify them if a particular page is available in another language. So my questions are:

1) How do I allow an anonymous user to change their preferred language?
2) How do I alert an anonymous user to the fact that a particular page is available in another language?

Comment: You should be able to add a language switcher block and have it appear on translated nodes, allowing anonymous users to pick the language.

Comment: [More info](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/d8-multi-lingual/#comment-2582878340): "You also need to have the url method enabled in the detection and selection page."

Comment: @WimMostrey If you can write a few sentences to summarize the tutorial (OP asks basically step 5) it would be quite a good answer :)

Comment: @Neograph734 You're right. I added an actual answer now instead of just a comment, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a detailed answer in step 5 of this guide: [5 Steps to Build a Drupal 8 Multi-lingual Site](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/d8-multi-lingual/).

Basically, this is what you need to do:

- Go to Admin > Structure > Blocks
- Click "Place blocks" on the desired region
- Click "Place block" next to the "Language Switcher" block
- Click "Save block"
- Go to a translated node and the Language Switcher will be working

[image]

As a sidenote mentioned in the comments of that guide: "You also need to have the url method enabled in the detection and selection page."

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question, go to detection and selection at /admin/config/regional/language/detection, check the User box, and uncheck the rest. Then save the page. After this, users will be able to edit their profile, and select their language there.

Comment: Sorry, this is for anonymous users - just visitors to the website. I will update the question to make that clearer.